# Images are replaced with blank white space while converting pdf to lower version (1.4 ) using ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

Images are replaced with blank white space while converting pdf to lower version (1.4 )  using ghostscript.
Everything seems fine but some content such as images of pdf was replaced. How to keep all content safe on converted pdf file?
Script i used:

```
shell_exec( "gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dSAFER  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH   -sOutputFile=$output $source");
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, first caveat, you aren't 'converting' your PDF file, you are making a new one. The new one has limitations not present in the original.

What version of Ghostscript are you using, on what platform, and where did you get it from ?

You are running with -dQUIET which limits the output you get, I would suggest that you don't do that, then you paste the backchannel from the application here which just might tell you something meaningful. You will, obviously, want to run that from the command line, not PHP.

However, its likely that nobody is going to be able to help you at all without seeing your original PDF file. If you think you have found a bug then your best bet is to open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com, where you can attach a specimen file that exhibits the problem. Alternatively post the PDF file somewhere public and put a link here.

Comment: my original pdf file is 
http://apps.dac.com.np/magazine/file/magazine/2013_5/full.pdf 
and converted pdf file is 
http://apps.dac.com.np/magazine/file/magazine/2013_5/converted.pdf
i also try removing -dQUIET but the result was same

Comment: I didn't expect a different result, but you haven't posted what the back channel output was either. You also haven't answered the questions about the version of Ghostscript you are using, the platform, and where you got GS from

Comment: I see from the PDF file that you are using Ghostscript 8.70, a version of the software which is now 5 years old. The current version is 9.16 and using your PDF file and command line I get a file which is apparently correct. It would be a good idea to check the software you use to see if new versions are available.

Comment: after updating the new version of ghostscript will it generate fine result with the code i used? or i have to change other part of script too?

Comment: I have no idea, firstly because I don't understand PHP and secondly because you've only posted one line of your script, how should I know what else you might have to change ? All I can tell you is that you are using a very elderly release of Ghostscript, which you say doesn't work, and that the current version does work with your file and command line.

Comment: i also try it on next server with new version of ghostscript but it doesn't work. php code has nothing to do on other lines. i have sent input and output file name in that script through php. conversion was done only through ghostscript. may be some parameter is worng which is removing some content.

Comment: And what version of Ghostscript are you using now ? You have never said, even though I have asked. Where did you get that version of Ghostscript ? Did you build it from source ? If not you should, package maintainers have been known to add code to Ghostscript, and also to use shared libraries instead of compiling the versions we ship. Its entirely possible that, for example, you are using a shared library version of LCMS2 which has a bug. As I said before, using your command line, and your input file, from a command shell, it works for me. You should try that too (and drop -dQUIET).